# Network Service Discovery: empty NsdServiceInfo in onServiceRegistered()-Callback of the RegistrationListener

Tags: android, mdns, nsd

When I register a service, following the guidelines from [android developers](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd), the `NsdServiceInfo`-Object does not contain all the information it should contain after the service was registered.

```
mRegistrationListener = new NsdManager.RegistrationListener() {

  @Override
  public void onServiceRegistered(NsdServiceInfo _NsdServiceInfo) {
  Log.i(TAG, "Service registered: "+_NsdServiceInfo);
  }

[...]

}
```

So when the `onServiceRegistered()`-callback is fired (that should only be, if the service was successfully registered) the log-message says:

```
Service registered: name: LTCServer_Niklas' Galaxy A3, type: null, host: null, port: 0, txtRecord:
```

So the, for the registration inserted, type (-http.-tcp.) was deleted and there is no host or port in the `_NsdServiceInfo`. This could not be correct.

This happens on various devices with various android-versions.

Does someone have an explanation about this?

Comment: Still facing the same issue. Does really nobody has an idea about that? Is it possible to report this bug somewhere at Google?

Answer (score 0):

You should use underscores instead of hyphens (-http.-tcp.) in your service type eg: _http._tcp.

> The syntax is `"_<protocol>._<transportlayer>".`

https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd#register